# Find $2^{2}+4^{2}….(2n)^{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sums-of-squares

I tried subtracting $1^{2}+3^{2}….n^{2}$ from $2^{2}+4^{2}….2n^{2}$, but that didn't work.

I know the answer is [image]

Comment: $(2k)^2=4\cdot k^2$. ${}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle 2^2 + 4^2 + \cdots + (2n)^2 = 2^2 (1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2)$. Plug in the value for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$ and you'll have the answer.